# Connecting AZURE Ubuntu Server using CLI

Tags: azure, command-line-interface, ubuntu-server, azure-vm-role

Recently I deployed two virtual machine WIN 10 and WIN Server 2012 which is easily to connect through GUI. Now I need to host the WordPress site on Ubuntu server using CLI. I have installed azure cli and run basic command like azure login, azure account list. It would be great help if I would get the appropriate instruction to connect the Ubuntu server and host WordPress to if possible. On deployment process I choose password instead of Public SSH Key

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're asking, but there should be plenty of documentation on the web (just search "install WordPress Ubuntu"). If you're trying to automate an ARM-based deployment, you can search for examples of those as well (but you'll need to plan out things such as whether you place your database engine in the same VM, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say broadly it involves 3 steps

1) Connect to your Ubuntu VM using SSH clients

http://www.putty.org/

2) Install wordpress following steps given in below link
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-on-ubuntu-14-04

3) Open ports from azure portal to your VM

http://azureblogger.com/2016/02/azure-vms-allowing-communication-on-selected-ports/